# Inner class as nested schema in Marshmallow?

Tags: python, marshmallow

Is it possible to use an inner class as a nested schema in Marshmallow (https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

I am trying to represent a hierarchical schema in Marshmallow which appears to be done through nested schemas. For example, I have a `Method` object, which has a `Params` attribute, which itself is an object. I could represent it as:

```
class MethodParamsSchema(Schema):
    a = fields.String()
    b = fields.Int()

class MethodSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String()
    params = fields.Nested(MethodParamsSchema)
```

What I would like to do is:

```
class MethodSchema(Schema):

   class MethodParamsSchema(Schema):
        a = fields.String()
        b = fields.Int()

    name = fields.String()
    params = fields.Nested('MethodSchema.MethodParamsSchema')
```

but this fails with the error:

> Class with name 'MethodSchema.MethodParamsSchema' was not found. You
>   may need to import the class.

The reason I would like to do this is because my schemas are fairly hierarchical and I'd like to group related items together. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `MethodSchema` doesn't exist until you've finished defining it, but the inner `MethodParamsSchema` is already complete; did using `fields.Nested(MethodParamsSchema)` in your second stricture not work?

Comment: doh! That works! I had tried that with the field declarations above the inner class, which failed as the inner class hadn't been declared by the time the fields were parsed and then didn't try it again when I switched the field and inner class declaration order. @jonrsharpe if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `'MethodSchema.MethodParamsSchema'` to `'MethodParamsSchema'` when defining the nested field resolves the problem for me:

```
params = fields.Nested('MethodParamsSchema')
```

Comment: ta. Looks like I can also just use the class name as long as I declare the inner class before the field: `params = fields.Nested(MethodParamsSchema)`